# Git log shows different author email when committing vs merging on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I just checked my `git log` and noticed that the email address for commits is different than for merges. I'm wondering what might be causing that so I can figure out how to make it so my email address for commits is the one I want.

(I've seen solutions for the problem - I'm more curious as to why this is happening.)

Comment: Is this *your* email address that's different or someone else's?

Comment: Are you performing the merges via GitHub, or with `git merge`?

Comment: It's my email address that is different. And I'm performing them via GitHub.

Comment: P.S. If you are using git-hub which your original tagging suggested, please mention it in the question and retag it back in.

Comment: You need to actually mention that you're using github in the question or you're likely to have the tag removed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you are merging using your github account and the email address for your github account is different than the email address you use in your `git config` on your machine.

You can change this for only one repository by using `git config user.email <email-address>` for your local repository. If this does not work, make sure you have not set the `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` or `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` variables.

Additionally, you can use --global to make changes for all your git repositories on your local EG: `git config --global user.email <email-address>`

Comment: That looks like it could fix the solution thanks. However I'm wondering why that was needed.

Comment: When you configure git, you usually don't set the user config details :D Also, people have multiple email addresses. Sometimes thing mess up man ;)